# converting docx file to html python3

Tags: python-3.x, mammoth

I have try to convert docx file to html file.
But could not convert to extract design,tables, image and etc..

**My code:**

```
 import mammoth

 doc_file = open('source_file.docx', "rb")
 html_file = open(output_file.html,'wb')
 result = mammoth.convert_to_html(doc_file)
 html_file.write(result.value.encode('utf8'))
 doc_file.close()
 html_file.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried with a simple docx?

Comment: yes, I have tried, but could not convert tables, images.

Comment: Please try https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx

Comment: and https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/docx/example.docx

Comment: Or https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/6/2/662F89E4-9340-4DDE-B28E-D1643681ADEB/Security%20in%20Office%20365%20Whitepaper.docx

Comment: All work fine for me. Could you look at the html source and see if the images are embedded? Which browser are you using to view them?

Comment: working with Fine, I want to page margin and tables data..